# Cannot print pdf from applicaton, lp works fine

Tags: pdf, printing, cups

Running Linux Mint 17.3 and I have installed a RICOH MP C3003 printer using cups with drivers obtained from http://www.openprinting.org [PDF](http://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=pxlcolor-Ricoh&printer=Ricoh-MP_C3003&show=0). The speciality may be that I have to use locked print at my work place.

I can print without problems from LibreOffice, Firefox, Thunderbird and I can also print pdfs via command line using lp and lpr. However, printing pdfs out of applications (Okular or Evince Document Viewer) fails. The file is send to the printer but at the printer it is added to the failed job list. The error at the printer say "You do not have the privileges to use this function. The job is cancelled" (originally in German "Sie haben keine Privilegien diese Funktion zu verwenden. Der Job wir abgebrochen.").

What can I do to make it possible to print pdfs from the respective applications?

Comment: Has noone any hint for me?